# Prevent white space in query being converted to %20

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following function in my model that I want to use to search for phrases and so on. However if I pass in more than one word the spaces are always converted to the %20 symbol which breaks my query. How do I avoid this?

Also is this type of query secure by default in codeigniter? or do I need to escape $term first?

```
function get_search_entries($limit, $start, $term)
 {

    $this->db->select('statuses.id, title, status, posted_by, created, rating, name');
    $this->db->from('statuses');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = statuses.category_id');

    $this->db->where('MATCH (title, status) AGAINST ("'.$term.'")', NULL, FALSE);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result();   
    }

    return false;      
  }
```

Comment: escape `term`. It can't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rawurldecode()` on your input strings.