# Compare two values with whitespace in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have two tables and I want to compare the values in my model, one from my product_category table, and another from product table.

[image]

[image]

```
public function selectcategory($cat)  
{  
    $this->db->where('product_cat',$cat);
    $query = $this->db->get('product_category');  
    return $query;  
}   

$cat="Health Care";
```

Health%20Care  how to remove %20 and compare these values?

Comment: possible duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970212/prevent-white-space-in-query-being-converted-to-20`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent white space in query being converted to %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970212/prevent-white-space-in-query-being-converted-to-20)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to remove %20 or %27 from string

```
urldecode( $cat )
```

Comment: @AdiSingh kidding.

Answer (score 0):

it is url encoded value. You have to decode vaue then compare it. which will convert `%20` to `space` again

```
public function selectcategory($cat)  
{  
     $cat =urldecode ($cat);
     $this->db->where('product_cat',$cat);
     $query = $this->db->get('product_category');  
     return $query;  
}
```